# Split image into smaller chunks,shuffle chunks and then save into my sd card in Android

Tags: android

I am working on a task in which i am split the image into smaller chunks and i have done it successfully [with the help of this link](http://androidattop.blogspot.com/2012/05/splitting-image-into-smaller-chunks-in.html?showComment=1401863710401),now my point is and i want to shuffle that chunks and then save into my sd card as it is,any help will be much appreciated Thanks in advance..

1. want to shuffle the chunks
2. after shuffling the chunks save that image as it is into my sd card

This is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Farhan,

In ChunkedImageActivity.java,
Use Collections.shuffle(imageChunks); after
ArrayList imageChunks = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("image chunks");

You will get the shuffled images.

To store these images in sdcard, use FileOutputStream.
Follow this link http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/android-tutorial-save-bitmap-image-on-android-sd-card/

Comment: Thnaks for your reply,i am getting images as shuffle thanks,but now tell me that when the images are shuffles then i want to save the shuffle images as it is save into my sd card as an one image,,have u get my point?

Comment: After Collections.shuffle(imageChunks); images are shuffled. and imageChunks arraylist is holding the shuffled images. Now iterate this  arraylist and save into sdcard one by one.